# How I handle returned data from $.ajax()?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to configure returned data from $.ajax() by jQuery...

My example is like that:

First of all I'm using codeigniter framework (just for attention)

Now by ajax I am calling function which returned group of divs

exp:

```
function my_function() {
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        print '<div class="block">'.$i.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Now by js code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/my_function",

    success: function(data){
        $('#div#container').html(data);
    }
});
```

Now all div (3 divs with block class) are appear at one time.(And I don't like that)

I want each one of the last three div appear sequentially (with slideDown for example)
Now my specifically question is:
How I configure data returned by ajax by loop for example????? to use slideDown for each div??

Comment: Can you re-read your question and structure it in better English please. I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fire the slide down function for each div once the other has completed if you want one div to display after the other.  You could build a recursive function so you can dynamically set indexes to start and end at certain values.  Of course, your div ids will have to be named properly so you can do something like this.

```
function doSlideDown(startIndex, endIndex){
    $('div#container'+startIndex).slideDown(500, function(){
        if(startIndex < endIndex){
            doSlideDown(startIndex+1, endIndex);
        }
    });
}

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "path/to/my_function",

success: function(data){
    $('div#container1').html(data);
    $('div#container2').html(data);
    $('div#container3').html(data);

    doSlideDown(1,3);
}
});
```

This will make sure that only one div slides out at a time.

Comment: Your script are great but for static number of div, and I want one div to display after the other but for dynamic number of divs(Unknown number), can you help?

Comment: Does the other answer not work?  You could count the number of divs once your done creating them based on the results.

Comment: Yes other answer is work but all divs are appear at one time.. anyway thank you for your useful answer.

Comment: will it not show same 3 divs three times in all the three containers ??

Answer (score 2):

add the `display:none;` initially

```
function my_function() {
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        print '<div class="block" style="display:none;">'.$i.'</div>';
    }
}
```

then

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/my_function",

    success: function(data){
        $('div#container').html(data);
           $('div.block').each(function(){
             $(this).slideDown(1000);
         });
    }
});
```